# Clojure zipper structure for a text editor (with maps and arrays)

Tags: java, data-structures, clojure, clojurescript, zipper

I am trying to make a simple text editor in clojure just to get familiar with it. I was thinking of using zippers for the structure and navigating and updating the editor.

I was thinking of storing the text of the editor in a document something like:

```
(def document-test {
:id "doc1"
:info {
    :title "Moluctular bio"
    :description "Test document"
}
:nodes [{
        :type "header"
        :content "This is a header"
        :id "h1"
    }
    {
        :type "p"
        :content "this is a paragraph"
        :id "p1"
    }
    {
        :type "todo"
        :content "Todo list"
        :id "t1"
        :nodes [
            {
                :type "todoelement"
                :content "Do this"
                :id "td1"
            }
            {
                :type "todoelement"
                :content "Do that"
                :id "td2"
            }]}]})
```

So I want to make a zipper that would be able to easily navigate this. Maybe a zipper would not be the best for this? But I was thinking of starting in the root. Going down would take you to the nodes of that children. So the top of the document is id h1.

I have the following, but it does not allow for the children to be an array:

```
(defn map-zip [m] 
  (zip/zipper 
    #(map? (second %)) 
        #(seq (second %)) 
       (fn [node children] [(first node) (into {} children)]) 
       [:root m]))
```

It's more expecting something like:

```
{:foo {:bar {:baz 2}}}
```

Any thoughts? I am open to changing the structure up completely if someone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a zipper to navigate that structure like the following:

```
(def z (zip/zipper 
        (constantly true) ; a node can always have children
        :nodes ; child nodes in the :nodes key, and keywords are functions
        (fn [node children]
          (update-in node [:nodes] #(into (or % []) children)))
        document-test))

(-> z
    zip/down
    zip/right
    zip/right
    (zip/insert-child {:type "h3" :id "thing1" :content "It's a h3!"})
    zip/down
    zip/right
    zip/right
    zip/node)
```

You may also want to look at the parse tree format of [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive) or [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) for ideas about structure. Reusing their structure may give you some interoperability you don't get with rolling your own.